# Painting a area inside image with JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a image with a lot of circles (without color). When user click in a specific circle, the application must ask the desired color and paint this circle with this color.

My image is like that:

[image]

So, I work with the following tecnologies: JSF (with Primefaces) + JPA + Maven + Spring  PostgreSQL. My initial solution is that: 
*"Introduce the image in XHTML page (with  tag) and with  tag, map all circle's area. So when user click inside a mapped area, i will launch a javascript code to draw a image with specific color in this area (throught the circle). "*

I think this solution a bit difficult to implement and a lot of work, not because of map tag, but because the process to repaint the area with another color with a Javascript code.

Exists some better solutions for this ? Maybe a API in JAVA or something more easy and productive ?

Comment: is it a requirement to have an image ? if it's not, why don't you consider a pure css, and a bit of jquery...

Comment: Yes, i can create the image dinamically. In fact, i'm think about use "canvas html5", this a great solutions and works fine.

Comment: yes might be a good solution

Comment: You can have an image generator I guess. The API and Class you need to know are mainly `ImageIO`, `BufferedImage`, and Graphics. Do you know how to generate an image in Java ?

Comment: this kind of work is for HTRML5 Canvas.